# Bedeutung von "sich überrascht zeigen"

Tags: meaning, verb-usage

Die Bundesregierung nach [dieser Schlagzeile](https://www.spiegel.de/ausland/tuerkei-recep-tayyip-erdogan-und-das-verhaeltnis-zur-hamas-a-a6f1b577-5aca-486a-8a6d-7b18a75b4be7) "zeigt sich überrascht" von Erdoğans jüngsten Tiraden. Ich habe die Bedeutung von "sich etw. zeigen" recherchiert und konnte keine klare Antwort bekommen. Einige Quellen deuten an, dass die Schlagzeile einfach gleich mit "Die Bundesregierung ist überrascht" wäre, andere, dass die Bundesregierung überrascht *wirkt*. Welches ist in diesem Fall richtig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wie immer ist es sinnvoll, im Zweifel ein Wörterbuch zu fragen. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zeigen) weiß zu "sich zeigen" (u.A):

1. *von andern zu sehen sein, irgendwo gesehen werden, sich sehen lassen*
2. *zum Vorschein kommen; sichtbar, erkennbar werden*
3. *in bestimmter Weise wirken, einen bestimmten Eindruck machen; sich als etwas erweisen, herausstellen*

Von diesen Bedeutungen ist hier wohl (3) am ehesten angebracht. Die Bundesregierung *macht also einen überraschten Eindruck*. Ob sie **wirklich überrascht** ist, bleibt größtenteils offen (aus dem Kontext heraus mag man möglicherweise annehmen, dass Erdoğan die Bundesregierung schon lange nicht mehr mit irgendwas überraschen kann, sondern man mit allem rechnet. Daher wäre "Die Bundesregierung **ist** überrascht" wahrscheinlich eine Überinterpretation - gespielte Überraschung ist in diplomatischen Kreisen jetzt nicht wirklich ungewöhnlich).

Die exakte Weise, auf die sich die Bundesregierung "überrascht zeigt", ist im vorliegenden Beispiel nicht impliziert. Man kann sich "überrascht zeigen", indem man staunend mit offenem Mund und großen Augen dasteht (unwahrscheinlich bei einer Pressekonferenz) oder aber, indem man sagt oder vorgibt, überrascht zu sein.

Comment: Danke Tofro. Ich glaube, die anderen zwei Antwortern sagen, dass "sich zeigen" in diesem Fall darauf schließen lässt, dass die Regierung nicht nur einen überraschten Endruck irgendwie macht, sondern genauer den Eindruck durch eine Aussage von Überraschung macht. Das würde etwa ausschließen, dass beim Journalist dieser Eindruck dadurch gemacht wurde, dass man bloß das offene Verhalten der Regierung beobachtet hätte. Würdest du da zustimmen?

Comment: Nun, man kann sich auch "überrascht zeigen", indem man einfach nur staunend mit offenem Mund dasteht. Das ist allerdings für eine Bundesregierung ziemlich unwahrscheinlich..... Daher geht hier wohl *nur aus dem Kontext hervor*, dass eine entsprechende Aussage gemacht wurde. In der reinen wörtlichen Bedeutung ist keine solche "Aussage" enthalten.

Comment: ...sondern es wird nur gesagt, dass irgendein Anhaltspunkt vorlag, der dazu geführt hat, dass die Regierung überrascht *erschien*. In der Diplomatie wird man allerdings eher nicht "wir sind überrascht", sondern eher "Erdoğans Verhalten hat in der Regierung ein gewisses Maß an Überrraschung ausgelöst" hören, dort befleißigt man sich einer sehr zurückhaltenden Ausdrucksweise :)

Comment: @tofro Bitte vielmals um Vergebung. Ich hatte kurz vergessen, dass das hier humorfreie Zone ist.

Comment: Mein Kommentar war in keiner Weise politisch. Aber ok.

Answer (score 1):

Von der Wortbedeutung heißt "zeigt sich überrascht" eindeutig, dass die Bundesregierung aussagt, sie sei überrascht. Ob sie tatsächlich überrascht *wirkt*, ist eine andere Frage, normalerweise hat sie von Sachverhalt schon vor der Pressekonferenz erfahren haben und nicht mehr akut überrascht sein.

Das muss nicht heißen, dass unterstellt wird, diese Überraschung sei gespielt. Ob die Überraschung echt ist oder nicht, wird kein Außenstehender erfahren, es sei denn, dass irgendwann interne Unterlagen diesbezüglich veröffentlicht werden.

Sachlich gesehen ist die Aussage "zeigt sich überrascht" korrekt. Die Aussage "Die Bundesregierung ist überrascht" hat dann die gleiche Bedeutung, wenn der Leser ergänzt "Laut Angaben der Bundesregierung".

Answer (score 0):

Diese Floskel *sich überrascht zeigen* soll ausdrücken, dass jemand (der Journalist) gefragt hat, was die Bundesregierung von Erdoğans Tiraden hält, und der Pressesprecher der Bundesregierung sagte, man sei überrascht.

Es handelt sich also um eine verklausulierte Form der indirekten Rede. Ob von der Frage überrascht oder von den Tiraden kann man leider nicht einmal aus dem Zusammenhang sicher sagen. Meistens heißt es, dass jemand von der Frage überrascht ist. Aber in diesem Zusammenhang denke ich eher, dass die Frage nahelag, und die Bundesregierung von den Tiraden kalt erwischt wurde.

Comment: Es gibt in der zitierten Schlagzeile nicht den geringsten Hinweis darauf, dass sich sie Überraschung darauf bezog, dass die Frage gestellt wurde.

Comment: Zwar kann auch indirekte Rede vorliegen, muss aber nicht. Wenn die Regierung gesagt hätte: "Damit haben wir nicht gerechnet" wäre "Die Regierung zeigt sich überrascht." eine plausible Darstellung des Vorgangs, aber indirekte Rede wäre nur etwas wie "damit habe sie nicht gerechnet".

Answer (score 0):

Bei allen Aussagen, in denen sich eine Verwaltung, höhere Institution wie die Regierung, oder ein Vorstand einer AG, also im weitesten Sinnen ein Sprecher einer Einrichtung "überrascht zeigt", gehe ich davon aus dass diese Stelle nach außen demonstriert (PR-Mitteilung etc) daß sie an solchen Vorfällen nicht beteiligt war und nicht darauf vorbereitet wurde und also keine Verantwortung übernimmt. Das sagt nicht über den tatsächlichen internen Kentnisstand aus. Das meistzitierte (satirisch-ironische) Beispiel für diesen Sprachgebrauch ist "die Bundesbahn wurde von dem Wintereinbruch überrascht."

Comment: Dein Beispiel "....wurde vom Wintereinbruch überrascht" läßt das "zeigte sich" (um das es hier hauptsächlich geht) leider vollkommen außer acht. Ersteres ist eine Tatsachenbehauptung. Zweiteres ist die Wiedergabe eines Eindrucks/einer Äußerung, die gemacht wurden.